# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in Facebook app

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Working with the Facebook PHP SDK. I was following along to a tutorial and ran into a problem with getting this page to load, this the was error that I got:

[image: screenshot of error]

Here is the code (App ID and Secret key have been removed). I got the file from the tutorial and filled some in from the file that is available on GitHub.

```
<?php

require 'src/facebook.php'

$app_id = ""; // has been removed
$secret = ""; // has been removed
$app_url = "http://apps.facebook.com/instahomework/";

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret). 
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' =>  $secret,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>php-sdk example 1 - user login and authorisation</title>
<style>
body { font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
a { text-decoration:none; }
a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>
</pre>
    <?php if ($user) { ?>
        <h2>Welcome</h2>
        <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture"><br/>
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a><br/>
        <br/>
        Gender : <?php echo $gender; ?><br/>
        Locale : <?php echo $locale; ?><br/>
        Username : <?php echo $username; ?><br/>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <strong><em>You have not granted this App permission to access your data. Redirecting to permissions request...</em></strong>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add a `}` after `$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();` to terminate the `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($user) {
 $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

one parenthesis is missing, I will  suggest you to use eclipse IDE, for such errors, it will automatically show you errors of these type when writing code

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah I was on Sublime, so I will look into Eclipse.